# JavaScriptの要素のつなげ方を教えていただけますでしょうか。

Tags: javascript

はじめまして、jsを覚えようとしていますが、要素のつなげ方でつまづいています。
下記では、エラーになってしまいます。何でつなげたらよいかどなたかご教示お願いできますでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

■やりたいこと
csvをhtmlに流し込みたく、jquery.csv.js（ライブラリ）を使用して、新規の style.jsにcsvの配列を入れたい。

■出来上がりのhtmlの形

```
<a href="test01.html"><img src="test01.jpg" alt="test02"/>
```

■＜imgタグのalt＝をどう連結？させてよいか分かりません。

```
for (var i = 1; i < csvList.length; i++) {
insert += '<a href="' + csvList[i][1] + '"><img src="' + csvList[i][1] +' " />';
```

■CSVの例
test01 [1]
test02 [2]

試しに、+でつなげたりしたらエラーになりました。
当方jsがよく分かっておらず…どなたかご教示お願いできますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

altも指定したいのであれば下記のようにつなげれば良いだけだと思います。
insertは初期化しましたか？

入力：

```
test01.html test01.jpg test02
```

式：

```
insert += ('<a href="' + csvList[i][0] + '"><img src="' + csvList[i][1] +'" alt="' + csvList[i][2] + '" ></a>');
```

Comment: Taizan Yonetujiさま

早速ご教示くださいまして、ありがとうございました。
できました！！！！
複数ある場合は、（）カッコでくくるんですね。勉強になりました。